# Generate fpdf files with while looping in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

i have some question for you guys .. i want to generate pdf files using php fpdf with different filename for each files .. here's my code

```
<?php
$no= 1;
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM file");
while($c_data = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
$cek_pengesahan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM simpeg_pangkat.pengesahan where 
tmt = '$data[tmt_baru]'");
$pengesahan = mysql_fetch_array($cek_pengesahan);
$file_name = 'File_'.$no++.'.pdf';
require('fpdf181/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','legal');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->SetXY(100,50-6);
$pdf->Cell(1000,10,'PETIKAN',0,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->SetXY(74,55-6);
$pdf->Cell(1000,10,'KEPUTUSAN BUPATI LUMAJANG',0,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->SetXY(79,60-6);
$pdf->Cell(1000,10,'NOMOR : '.$pengesahan[no_sk],0,'C');
$pdf->SetXY(99,65-6);
$pdf->Cell(1000,10,'TENTANG',0,'C');
$pdf->Output("$file_name",'F');
}
?>
```

it suppossed to be generate (File_1.pdf,File_2.pdf,File_3.pdf) files . but after executing this code , it only generate File_1.pdf .. File_2.pdf and File_3.pdf are not generated.

Comment: I don't see you using this variable `$c_data` from you loop; why?

Comment: Then you have this variable `$pengesahan` which is unassigned. Then `[no_sk]`; that stands to be treated as a constant. You should enable error reporting.

Comment: Your loop is running twice, check your loop first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the require('fpdf181/fpdf.php'); out of the loop or use require_once('fpdf181/fpdf.php'); As you are using it inside the loop it will include the same class on the 2nd iteration which will result in a duplicate class definition.

Also, the parameters for the Output method should be reversed as follows

```
$pdf->Output('F',"$file_name");
```

As per the documentation, the Output function is as follows

string Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])

Description

Send the document to a given destination: browser, file or string. In the case of a browser, the PDF viewer may be used or a download may be forced. 
The method first calls Close() if necessary to terminate the document.
Parameters

dest

Destination where to send the document. It can be one of the following:

I: send the file inline to the browser. The PDF viewer is used if available.

D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.

F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).

S: return the document as a string.

The default value is I.

name

The name of the file. It is ignored in case of destination S.
The default value is doc.pdf.

Comment: so i have reverse my code into $pdf->Output('F',"$file_name"); ?

Comment: put this require('fpdf181/fpdf.php'); out of the loop or use require_once('fpdf181/fpdf.php'); As you are using it inside the loop it will include the same class on the 2nd iteration